# Asking the teacher if we have a lecture to attend or not

Tags: masters

Good morning miss 
We are wondering about our next session! If we are obliged to attend Saturday lecture or we are asked to wait till they make some schedule changes as they promised us

Have a good day

Comment: I have no idea what your question is saying.

Comment: Exactly. I, too, have no idea what your question is saying.

Comment: We have a lecture this saturday but we were asking the administration to modify the time table therefore we won't study on saturday but we don't know yet if they made some changes or not yet so we are asking the teacher for a clear answer about attending Saturday's lecture or not

Comment: What are you asking _us_?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Dear Professor
>
> We have not received information whether the time table has been modified, after we made a plead for it. Do we have a lecture on the Saturday as in the old time table? Thank you for your answer in advance.
>
> Regards
>
> You